# How to pass Spark executor parameters to DBT?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dbt, livy

I am using DBT with spark-livy-adapter. And I want to pass spark-conf properties like --num_executors via DBT-cli command:
like this

`dbt run --select my_model  --spark_conf "num-executors":5`

Please me help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I have added the `livy_session_parameters` in parameter in the profile.yml file and added the value as a variable then I'm passing the executor number as a variable and it's working fine.

My profile.yml file look like this

```
dbt_project:
  outputs:
   my_spark_livy:
     livy_session_parameters:
       spark.executor.instances: "{{ var('num_executor') }}"
  target: my_spark_livy
```

DBT cli command:

```
dbt run --select my_model --vars '{"num_executor" :"10"}'
```